# changing value of isset

Tags: php, forms, session

I'm wondering if it's possible to manually change the value of an isset value. That is, to do something like this:

```
isset($_POST['search_user']) = true;
```

Why I want to do this: I have two different "submit" forms on one page. When one form is submitted, I want to capture all the values of that form into SESSION variables. However, when the other form is submitted, the SESSION variables are wiped out (since the first form is not, technically, submitted anymore).

My idea was that, if the second form is submitted, then automatically set the value of the first form to true

Comment: Are you losing your session data from one page load/submit to the next?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, if a second form is submitted, why not just destroy the current session and start new sessions using the variables posted from the new form?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php

```
session_destroy();
```

...Or, you can set another session variable if the second form is submitted:

```
if (isset($_POST['search_user'])) {

    $_SESSION['search_user'] = "true";

}

if ($_SESSION['search_user'] == "true") {

    // Second form was submitted

}
```

Comment: Or alternatively, if the second form is submitted, just skip all the _SESSION stuff completely.

Comment: But I need to keep all the user input from the first form (on the same page, too). I checked out session_destroy(), but it does not seem to do what I need

Comment: @JohnRobinson Thanks for the answer. I tried it, but I don't see how it can help me "keep" the user input from the first form

Comment: `if ($_SESSION['search_user'] == "true") { // Do whatever with the first form data here }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to define a name and a value for each submit button, so you retrieve this in the PHP file and do what you want, according you need. For instance:

**HTML to the first form:**

```
<form name="form1" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="1" name="button01">
</form>
```

**HTML to the second form:**

```
<form name="form2" action="page2.php" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="1" name="button02">
</form>
```

Then you can detect the form thas was submited doing this in `page2.php`:

```
if($_POST['button01'] == "1")
{
     // Do what you need based on form1 submit
}
elseif($_POST['button02'] == "1")
{
     // Do what you need based on form2 submit
}
```

Try this and then leave some comment telling if it helps you.